# Adding Routing to a Vue.js cli 3.0 app

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

The new Vue.js 3.0 plugin architecture is nice, but it seems to to be missing a router plugin. If I choose not to install routing when I first create the project (`vue create my-project`), I'd expect that I could change my mind later and add routing with something like `vue add @vue/router`, but that plugin doesn't appear to exist.  Is there a way to add routing from the CLI after the fact?

Comment: vuejs 3 or vue-cli 3? if you are not talking about vuejs 3, you can just follow this guide to add plugin=router after project created. [Vue Router installation Guide for NPM](https://router.vuejs.org/en/installation.html)

Comment: Yeah, vue-cli 3.  I've already added the routing manually, but I was surprised that there wasn't a plugin I could use to do that setup for me since there appears to be one built into the initial cli install.

Comment: @Sphinx I believe Vue 3 does not exist yet. And `vue-cli` 3 is a completely different thing, the router is probably packed into `vue-cli-service`

Answer (score 127):

After some experimenting with vue-cli3, i found that you can use `vue add` to setup components you missed.

Use `vue add router` That set up the routing and created some sample components Home and About.

This also work for other modules like adding vuetify with `vue add vuetify`. You can read more about vue add from the [plugins and presets guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#installing-plugins-in-an-existing-project)

Comment: Thanks for saving my time :-)

Comment: Be warned! I just did this and it overwrote my App.vue file. Maybe rename your App.vue file before using vue add router.

Comment: Safest way is to first commit all your changes before running any vue tasks.

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at the issue page here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1202, the conclusion is you can't use cli to add router if you didn't choose router initially.
With three reasons:

1. Late-adding router when you've already modified the entry file is extremely fragile.
2. If you haven't modified the file much, you can just re-generate the project instead.
3. If we only add the dependency and skip the file-modifying part, then it's easier to just npm install vue-router or yarn add vue-router.

Comment: Actually, you *can* use `vue-cli` to late-add `vue-router` (as of `vue-cli` 3.0.0) with `vue add router`. Despite the comment you mention, the feature was added anyway.

Comment: But it doesn't update files you've changed or removed. So not that useful if you've been working for a while.